# The cost model of C math.h and string.h in x86

Tags: c

Is there a cost model of C operations? I'm looking for something like [this](http://scripts.mit.edu/~6.006/fall08/wiki/index.php?title=Python_Cost_Model) but for C's `math.h` and `string.h` in x86? There are academic papers about his, see [here](http://hal.inria.fr/hal-00702665), but nothing like in the page I pointed to.

Comment: Most standard library functions are very straightforward and if you're interested in their complexity (the magic O-notation thing:), it's usually easy to guess it. The actual numbers will depend on the CPU, compiler and the details of the implementation of those functions. Other things (operators) are very primitive and transform into just a few instructions with more or less linear execution (notable exceptions: arithmetic operations not supported directly by the CPU, e.g. multiplication, division, floating point).

Comment: @Dervin Well, since math.h and string.h functions are just that - functions, you could look at the code of their implementations. Most of them are written in the C language (however, lower-level functions might be written in assembly).

Answer (score 2):

In C, basically everything that is not a function call can have only a fixed number of CPU operations. This is because C has only integral built-in types.

Unlike C++, there can be no hidden (as in - non-obvious) function calls, i.e. no constructors, destructors, or operator overloading.

**Edit**

---

As @cHao and @nneonneo points out, there is an exception, if the platform doesn't have floating-point support, or even integer division support, those could trigger hidden execution of compiler-provided library functions.

Comment: Why the downvote? The built-in types is something that clarifies the issue.

Comment: `x/y`, where `x` and `y` are both integers, may trigger the use of a C library for division. This can take a lot more cycles than, say, an increment operation. A cost model there would still be valuable to have.

Comment: C also runs on CPUs that don't have hardware multipliers or dividers, for example.

Comment: @satuon: I like your answer, please don't delete it.

Comment: (minor nitpick: the library functions are usually compiler-provided, e.g. `libgcc.a`)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing for C.  The "cost model" for C operations depends *entirely* on the compiler, CPU, OS, etc.  Some might not have the operations listed; some might have to do additional work to cast integers, multiply/divide, etc.

Comment: So the page I linked to is only at the level of the Python runtime and has no impact on the execution of machine code?

Comment: It analyzes the total running time (including the machine code), but it is specific to the machine (in this case, an "IBM Thinkpad T43p with a 1.86GHz Pentium M processor and 1.5GB RAM".)

Comment: @nneonneo: Yep, well, that's what I meant. I refined the question to see what I get.

Comment: @Dervin: You'd still have to specify which compiler was used as well, what optimization options were used (if any), etc.  Past a certain point, it gets so specific as to be useless.

Comment: @cHao: I agree, it's just weird that after all these years, gcc, clang, or any of the others don't have a cost model for each architecture... I believe(d) this kind of documentation (even for each particular arch) should be available. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DervinThunk: They don't have that info because they don't care.  C will almost certainly run as fast as it can on each machine, which for the most part means one or two operations per expression.  Execution times are measured in *nanoseconds*, not microseconds.  For FP and string ops, it's dependent on the CPU *and* the contents of the C library, which could conceivably be totally rewritten between compiler releases if they wanted to.  So now, there's the *compiler version* to worry about.  It's not worth the trouble.